# For loop in java not working

Tags: java, for-loop, random

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomHomework
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i;
        Random generator = new Random();
        double randomDecimals = generator.nextDouble()-.04;
        int randomNumber = generator.nextInt(9)+10;
        for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)
        {
            if(randomNumber >= 10.00)
            {
                System.out.println(randomNumber + randomDecimals);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am having a problem with the setup of my for loop and cannot figure it out... It runs perfectly fine when I remove the for loop.

As you can see I tried declaring the i previously but it made no difference.

Comment: Please post your code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not as an external link.

Comment: Switch `>` with `<` in your loop condition.

Comment: Your condition is wrng

Comment: When is `0 > 100` true?

Comment: After you fix your for loop, your program still won't work since it will either skip over printing the `randomNumber` 100 times, or print the same `randomNumber` 100 times. You presumably wanted to generate a new random number inside the loop body?

Comment: Also, since you're adding 10 to it, `randomNumber` will always be greater than or equal to 10. You're generating numbers in the range 10 - 18 (inclusive).

Answer (score 12):

```
for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)
```

This says: start with i set to zero and continue as long as it is greater than 100.

This stops right away

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the condition of the loop

`for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)`

The condition should be `i < 100`

Answer (score 1):

Your loop condition is always false. You start from `i = 0` and say run while `i > 100`. However, **0 is never > 100** so your loop never happens.

Change

```
for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)
```

To

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change:

```
for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)
```

to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

for the loop to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i = 0; i > 100; i++)
```

else it would end as soon as it starts since you are checking `i > 100`

Answer (score -1):

You need to use
`for(i =0; i<100; i++)`
cuz your version is ended right away